# MUI Autocomplete with axios call to select or add new option [ codesandbox included ]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

> I'm trying to make an Autocomplete input for categories from an API response and allow the user to be able to create one if he didn't find
> a match.

---

### Issues:

**1- How to avoid Non-unique when I have same key which is name can I make on ID cause it's unique?**

```
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Flour & Bread Mixes`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behaviour is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

**2- The dialog for entring new category doesn't open and I don't see any errors in the console**

---

Code Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/asynchronous-material-demo-forked-70eff?file=/demo.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete , { createFilterOptions } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import parse from 'autosuggest-highlight/parse';
import match from 'autosuggest-highlight/match';
import axios from "axios";
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Input } from "@material-ui/core";


export default function Asynchronous() {

  const filter = createFilterOptions();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const loading = open && options.length === 0;


  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  const [openDialog, toggleOpenDialog] = React.useState(false);

  
  const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogValue({
      name: '',
      slug: '',
      image: '',
    });

    toggleOpenDialog(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setCategories({
      name: dialogValue.name,
      slug: dialogValue.slug,
      image: dialogValue.image
    });

    handleClose();
  };


  const [dialogValue, setDialogValue] = React.useState({
    name: '',
    slug: '',
    image: '',

  });


  React.useEffect(() => {
      let active = true;

      if (!loading) {
          return undefined;
      }

      (async () => {

          var config = {
              method: 'get',
              url: 'https://null.free.mockoapp.net/getCategories',
          };

          axios(config)
              .then(function (response) {
                  response.data = response.data.filter((category) => category.name)
                  if (active) {
                      setOptions([...response.data]);
                  }

              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
          });


      })();

      return () => {
          active = false;
      };
  }, [loading]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!open) {
          setOptions([]);
      }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <>
          <Autocomplete
          id="asynchronous-demo"
          open={open}
          limitTags={3}
          onOpen={() => {
              setOpen(true);
          }}
          onClose={() => {
              setOpen(false);
          }}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => {
              // Value selected with enter, right from the input
              if (typeof option === 'string') {
                  return option;
              }
              // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
              if (option.inputValue) {
                  return option.inputValue;
              }
              // Regular option
              return option.name;
          }}
          options={options}
          loading={loading}
          multiple
          renderInput={(params) => (
              <>
                  <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Asynchronous"
                      InputProps={{
                          ...params.InputProps,
                          endAdornment: (
                              <React.Fragment>
                                  {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                                  {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                              </React.Fragment>
                          ),
                      }}
                  />
                  {console.log(options)}
              </>
          )}
          renderOption={(props, option, { inputValue }) => {
              const matches = match(option.name, inputValue);
              const parts = parse(option.name, matches);

              return (
                  <li {...props}>
                      <div>
                          {parts.map((part, index) => (
                              <span
                                  key={index}
                                  style={{
                                      color: part.highlight ? "red" : 'inherit',
                                      fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400,
                                  }}
                              >
                                {part.text}
                              </span>
                          ))}
                      </div>
                  </li>
              );
          }}

          value={categories}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            if (typeof newValue === 'string') {
              // timeout to avoid instant validation of the dialog's form.
              setTimeout(() => {
                toggleOpenDialog(true);
                setDialogValue({
                  name: newValue,
                  slug: '',
                  image: ''
                 });
              });
            } else if (newValue && newValue.inputValue) {
              toggleOpenDialog(true);
              setDialogValue({
                name: newValue.inputValue,
                slug: '',
                image: ''

              });
            } else {
              setCategories(newValue);
            }
  
          }}
          filterOptions={(options, params) => {
              const filtered = filter(options, params);
              const { inputValue } = params;
              const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.name);
              if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
                  filtered.push({
                      inputValue:inputValue,
                      name: `Add "${inputValue}"`,
                  });
              }
              return filtered;
          }}
          selectOnFocus
          clearOnBlur
          handleHomeEndKeys

      />
      <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleClose}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <DialogTitle>Add a new film</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            Did you miss any film in our list? Please, add it!
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            value={dialogValue.name}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setDialogValue({
                ...dialogValue,
                name: event.target.value,
              })
            }
            label="title"
            type="text"
            variant="standard"
          />
          <TextField
            margin="dense"
            id="slug"
            value={dialogValue.slug}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setDialogValue({
                ...dialogValue,
                slug: event.target.value,
              })
            }
            label="slug"
            type="text"
            variant="standard"
          />
          <Input
            margin="dense"
            id="image"
            value={dialogValue.image}
            onChange={(event) =>
              setDialogValue({
                ...dialogValue,
                image: event.target.value,
              })
            }
            label="image"
            type="file"
            variant="standard"
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button type="submit">Add</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </form>
    </Dialog>

    </>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a lot of mistakes in your code so I made a new working fork on Codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/asynchronous-material-demo-forked-oeg2p?file=/demo.js

Notes:

1. save the api response in a state instead of doing an API call
   whenever the user opens the dropdown.
2. you could make an API request in handleSubmit function to create a new category in the back-end
3. handleFormSubmit will output the value of Autocomplete.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Read more about autocomplete at
https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out on this